# Datagrid Duplication due to Select Statement VB

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I am using an Access database, I believe the problem lies in my SQL statement. I have a relational database, with two tables -

```
StaffDetails [columns(
StaffID, 
FirstName, 
LastName)]
```

and

```
StaffTraining [columns(
StaffID, 
Month)].
```

I have a combobox (`cbMonth`) and dependent on what month is chosen if the user selects 'January' then I would like the datagrid (`DGTraining`) to show the First Name and Last Name of the members of staff whose ID are within the chosen month. Sorry if this is not the clearest explanation, hopefully my code below makes my issue clearer:

```
Dim SqlQuery As String = "SELECT [StaffDetails.StaffID], [StaffDetails.FirstName], [StaffDetails.LastName], [StaffTraining.StaffID] FROM [StaffDetails], [StaffTraining] WHERE StaffTraining.TrainingMonth='" & cbMonth.Text & "'"
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(SqlQuery, conn)
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "Training")
    Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables("Training")

    With DGTraining
        .AutoGenerateColumns = True
        .DataSource = ds
        .DataMember = "Training"
    End With
```

Comment: You are missing a join statement and are just cross joining two tables.  [StaffDetails], [StaffTraining].   What is the key between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing your join and are getting a cross join.  2 ways of addressing:

```
FROM [StaffDetails] inner join [StaffTraining] on  [StaffDetails].staffID = [StaffTraining].staffID
```

That is the join logic thats more common and easier to read.  You could add to your where clause (old method, harder to read and not as commonly accepted:

```
...where [StaffDetails].staffID = [StaffTraining].staffID and ...
```

Comment: I imagine INNER JOIN would work in this case, which would probably be quicker.

Comment: Thanks Remou.    @Hayden - you probably want an inner join not a left join...inner join will drop rows that have no monthly match, so I would suggest that.  editting answer

Comment: @Twelfth below is my new code, still not working, any ideas?
    Dim SqlQuery As String = "SELECT [StaffDetails.StaffID], [StaffDetails.FirstName], [StaffDetails.LastName], FROM [StaffDetails] INNER JOIN [StaffTraining] ON [StaffDetails].StaffID = [StaffTraining].StaffID WHERE [StaffDetails].StaffID = [StaffTraining].StaffID AND [StaffTraining].TrainingMonth='" & cbMonth.Text & "'"

Comment: Hmm...need to troubleshoot where the error is with you then. If you are listing multiple months, you will need to use IN and not =. Replace your variable with the word 'january' and run the query directly against your database...are those the rows you want?

Answer (score 0):

Your last comment needs amending like this...

```
Dim SqlQuery As String = "SELECT [StaffDetails.StaffID], [StaffDetails.FirstName],
[StaffDetails.LastName], FROM [StaffDetails]
INNER JOIN [StaffTraining] ON [StaffDetails].StaffID = [StaffTraining].StaffID
WHERE [StaffTraining].TrainingMonth='" & cbMonth.Text & "'"
```

Also... dependant on how you have set up cbMonth you may want cbMonth.SelectedValue or cbMonth.SelectedText

Comment: I've just edited my comments as I spotted you were using a combibox.